# TetGen generates tets for empty chambers/holes in a model

Tags: tetgen

I am using tetgen to generate meshes for my research.

My models have empty internal chambers inside them. For example, an empty box of size (5,5,5) inside a box of size (10, 10, 10). See image:[image: Box chamber within a bigger box]

The problem is that tetgen generates tetrahedrons inside the empty chamber. Why? Is there a way to avoid it?

I tried using -YY, -q, -CC, -c, and their combinations, but all had the same problem, and did not give insight on the error. (http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/1.5/doc/manual/manual005.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved it was to create a *.poly* file (http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/fformats.poly.html). I created a *.poly* file from a *.off* file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OFF_(file_format)), which I could export from *OpenScad*.

***.poly* file has 4 parts, from which the 3rd specifies holes in the object.** You need to tell *TetGen* where you have holes in the object.
The way to do it, is **by specifying one point in the hole/chamber**.

A possible .poly file would look like this:

part1 - vertices:

```
40 3 0 0
0 0.2 0 1 
1 0.161803 0.117557 0 
...
```

part2 - faces:

```
72 0
1
3 0 1 2
1
3 1 0 3
...
```

part3 - holes <============== the one I needed

```
1
1 0 0 0.5   <=== this is a point, which I know is inside my hole/chamber
```

So here is the file, without any breaks, just in case:

```
40 3 0 0
0 0.2 0 1 
1 0.161803 0.117557 0 
...

72 0
1
3 0 1 2
1
3 1 0 3
...

1
1 0 0 0.5
```